# Rails has_many :through does not save relations or saves corrupted one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, model, associations

I have models:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :cruise_lines, through: :specializations
end

class CruiseLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :agencies, through: :specializations
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency, inverse_of: :specializations
  belongs_to :cruise_line, inverse_of: :specializations
end
```

In my view I have such part with checkboxes in the form in HAML

```
= agency.collection_check_boxes(:cruise_line_ids, CruiseLine.all, :id, :name) do |specialization|
  .checkbox
    = specialization.label do
      = specialization.check_box type: "checkbox"
      = specialization.object.name
```

This generates valid HTML ending with (it shows correctly already connected cruise lines to current agency - if I add needed entries directly to DB)

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label for="agency_cruise_line_ids_27"><input type="checkbox" value="27" name="agency[cruise_line_ids][]" id="agency_cruise_line_ids_27" />
        TransOcean Kreuzfahrten
    </label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="agency[cruise_line_ids][]" value="" />
```

When saving form in log I see such params `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some-long-token", "agency"=>{"name"=>"Test agency", "website"=>"http://www.bla-bla.com", "description"=>"", "booking_email"=>"", "booking_phone"=>"", "optional_booking_phone"=>"", "working_hours"=>"", "cruise_line_ids"=>["1", "2", "15", "16", "27", "28", ""]}, "commit"=>"Update"}`

Part that saves edited agency data and specialization (that is relation to `CruiseLine`)

```
attributes = params.require(:agency).permit(
  :name, :website, :description, :booking_email, :booking_phone, 
  :optional_booking_phone, :working_hours, :cruise_line_ids
)
agency.specializations.build(attributes[:cruise_line_ids])
agency.update_attributes(attributes)
```

Agency data is saved without any problems, but in the `specializations` table is saved broken entry: `agency_id` with correct agency id, but `cruise_line_id` equals to empty string!!! Each time I save the form, one more corrupted relation is added to the existing ones.

### Questions:

**1)** how to save relations in my case, cause current code simply does not work?

**2)** how to update those relations (that is in case if checkbox is unselected and form is saved, the unselected relations also should be removed)?

**3)** why does in params `cruise_line_ids` array's last element is empty string? And why is it generated by collection_ckeckbox_helper?

Please, help. I'm struggling with this 4 hours :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in two places (incorrect building and redundant index in relations table):

I replaced this code

```
agency.specializations.build(attributes[:cruise_line_ids])
```

with the following:

```
attributes[:cruise_line_ids].each do |cruise_line_id|
  if cruise_line_id.to_i > 0     # to skip last empty string element?!
    agency.specializations.build(cruise_line_id: cruise_line_id)
  end
end
```

and made small modification in the code (`:cruise_line_ids => []` - this part) below:

```
attributes = params.require(:agency).permit(
  :name, :website, :description, :booking_email, :booking_phone, 
  :optional_booking_phone, :working_hours, :cruise_line_ids => []
)
```

After that it started causing some `PG::uniqueviolation` error. It turned out to be a problem with compound unique index. Having examined the SQL log it turned out that my relations were saved twice (when building and the second time when updating attributes), so I put code that updated attributes before the block with building relations and everything became fine and perfect :)